# How to prevent to break line in C at the end of for loop before ;

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code, formatter

Actually my options are : `"C_Cpp.clang_format_fallbackStyle": "{ BreakBeforeBraces: Linux, IndentWidth: 4, ColumnLimit: 80, UseTab: Never, SortIncludes: false, AlignAfterOpenBracket: DontAlign }"`

I have:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    ;
```

I want:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++);
```

Comment: The first makes it clearer that the empty loop wasn't a mistake. And if it was, it draws the attention more easily.

Comment: In fact, clang actually gives a warning for the second form, suggesting to use the first form.

Comment: @AdrianMole does it give a warning for the first version too?

Comment: @WeatherVane No. I guess that why it suggests it.

Comment: So clang is warning about the code typography style, not its functionality?

Comment: Actually, I can't immediately generate the warning, but I have seen it in my real code. But yeah, it's something along the lines of *"possible misplaced semicolon - place on a separate line to silence this warning"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue and it make a warning. The only way is to write this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {}
```

Comment: Writing it this way is *vastly* clearer anyway. Good formatter/clang.